# How to write a starmap-like function without using the builtin map or starmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, starmap

This is the task:

> Make a function `my_map_k` that as arguments takes a function f and k
>   lists L<sub>1</sub>,...,L<sub>k</sub>, for an arbitrary k ≥ 1, and returns the list
>   [f(L<sub>1</sub>[0],...,L<sub>k</sub>[0]),...,f(L<sub>1</sub>[n-1],...,L<sub>k</sub>[n-1])], where n is the length
>   of the shortest L<sub>i</sub> list.
>
> Hint. Use Python's `*` notation to handle an arbitrary number of lists as arguments.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> my_map_k(lambda x, y, z: x*y*z, [3, 2, 5], [2, 7, 9], [1, 2])
> ```
>
> should return `[6, 28]`.

This is how far I've gotten, but I'm stuck.

```
def my_map_k(f, *L):
    n = len(min(*L, key=len))
    x=0
    while x < n:
        return [f(*L[x],) for x in L]

my_map_k(lambda x, y, z: x*y*z, [3, 2, 5], [2, 7, 9], [1, 2])
```

The problem is, I cannot just say that there are 3 lists, because there could be more. Furthermore I cannot see how to take the first element out of all three lists.

Comment: It’s the `map` function.  Not `starmap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to take the ***n***th element from each list in turn, and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to call the supplied function with each group of arguments so generated:

```
def my_map_k(f, *lists):
    return [f(*args) for args in zip(*lists)]
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> my_map_k(lambda x, y, z: x*y*z, [3, 2, 5], [2, 7, 9], [1, 2])
[6, 28]
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
def my_map_k(f, *L):
    z = zip(*L)
    l = list(z)
    return ([f(*x) for x in l])

my_map_k(lambda x, y, z: x*y*z, [3, 2, 5], [2, 7, 9], [1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which does not use builtin map function:

```
from itertools import starmap

def my_map_k(f, *L):
    return list(starmap(f, zip(*L)))
```

Comment: I don't think I'm alloved to use starmap neither. I think the point is to make a recursive function or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with no helper functions:

```
from operator import add

def my_map_k(f, *L):
    ind = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield f(*[l[ind] for l in L])
        except IndexError:
            break
        else:
            ind += 1

result = my_map_k(add, range(5), range(5))
print(list(result))
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```